# Flutter - pick and upload image work while debugging and don't work in apk app-release

Tags: android, debugging, flutter, apk, release

My app should take an image from gallery and upload it to server and show it.

To pick the image I used:

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
```

To upload it I used:

```
String uploadedImageUrl = await AmazonS3Cognito.upload(....);
```

Picking image is working in **debug**, but not working when I build an **APK**!

I thought the problem is in **Android Manifest**,

My Manifest file is hovered with yellow color and show this message:

[image: warning in manifest]

And above `<application...> ... </application>` I add those permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But I still have the problem with the **release version**.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?